# Internet doesn't works in browser if network interface is changed

Tags: networking, wireless, bug-reporting, atheros, tethering

I am using atheros wifi adapter for connecting to access point,
but some time I switch to mobile data via RNDIS Ethernet(USB Tething).

Now if I switch back to WIFI after sometime, Browser simply doesn't work(Firefox/Chromium),
although

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

works and even other application such as skype,CloudDrives etx.

Seems like a bug to me .

Any suggestion ???

**Short Fix :REBOOT**

Answer (score 0):

This could be a DNS issue.

Try to ping by name ("ping google-public-dns-a.google.com"), ping by name the site you are trying to reach ("ping askubuntu.com"), open the site in the browser by IP address (http://216.58.213.238 for google.com).

Check DNS address in the network settings of the active adapter.